# How can I get over this Node.js iconv module installation error

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am getting the below error while I am installing 'Iconv' module in node js project with below  command `npm install iconv`. What might be the issue?

```
C:\Drive\GIT\ooxp-service-fileimport\node_modules\iconv&gt;if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node &quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js&quot; rebuild )  else (node &quot;&quot; reb
uild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the &quot;/m&quot; switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the
 SDK version in the project property pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting &quot;Retarget solution&quot;. [C:\Drive\GIT\ooxp-service-fileimport\node_modules\iconv\build\iconv.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command &quot;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe&quot; &quot;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js&quot; &quot;rebuild&quot;
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Drive\GIT\ooxp-service-fileimport\node_modules\iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v4.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv &quot;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe&quot; &quot;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js&quot; &quot;install&quot; &quot;iconv&quot;
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! iconv@2.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@2.2.1 install script &#39;node-gyp rebuild&#39;.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the iconv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs iconv
npm ERR! Or if that isn&#39;t available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls iconv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Drive\GIT\ooxp-service-fileimport\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Which version of iconv? Did you tried with an older version?

Comment: I have installed node-v4.5.0.
In that I am trying to install iconv module By running below command in termils window.
npm install iconv

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Build failure. You need to have C++ installed on your PC. Try following these tutorials.

https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/

Documentation : https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp